# How to change the path in files when moving a directory in the PhpStorm

Tags: optimization, automation, phpstorm

In PhpStorm there is a function, when you re-create a file, it is renamed in the entire project. Neither can I find out if there is a function so that when transferring one folder to another.

For example:

- in the `/abc/def/ghi/` structure
- you need to move `/ghi/` directly under `/abc/`
- and that in the files where the mention of `/abc/def/ghi/` will became `/abc/ghi/`

The functional as in renaming interests. About the mass replacement through **Ctrl + Shift + R** I know, but then you must first move the folder, then look for files where something is wrong, but I want it to be more automated and do it all myself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, it works just like this, I just installed the old version, updated it, everything works as I wanted out of the box, there's nothing to think about.

Was PhpStorm 7